# install procenv on 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to troubleshoot a failing upstart script, and for that I need procenv. 
I tried `sudo apt-get install procenv` But that fails with `E: Unable to locate package procenv`. What can I do more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package isn't available for Ubuntu 12.04 in the official repositories. But you could try to use the PPA `ppa:jamesodhunt/procenv-daily`

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jamesodhunt/procenv-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install procenv
```

---

As an alternative it is always possible to compile your own version

```
sudo apt-get install git checkinstall
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/jamesodhunt/procenv.git
cd procenv
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```